# Im having a trouble getting my data from mysql db using $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

I cant get the data from my db which I need to display it.

```
<label style="font-size:20px"><b>Doctor:</b></label><br>
        <select name="doctor" id="doctor-list" class="demoInputBox" style="width:100%;height:35px;border-radius:9px">
        <option value="">Select Doctor</option>
        <?php
        session_start();
        $mid=$_SESSION['mgrid'];
        $sql1="SELECT * FROM doctor where did in(select did from doctor_availability where cid in (select cid from manager_clinic where mid=$mid));";
         $results=$conn->query($sql1); 
        while($rs=$results->fetch_assoc()) { 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rs["did"]; ?>"><?php echo "Dr. ".$rs["name"]; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label><b>Date:</b></label><br>
        <input type="date" name="dateselected" required><br><br>
        <br>
            <button type="submit" style="position:center" name="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

        include 'dbconfig.php';
        $did=$_POST['doctor'];
        $cid=1;
        $dateselected=$_POST['dateselected'];
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM book WHERE DOV='". $_POST['dateselected']."' AND DID= $did AND CID= $cid order by Timestamp ASC";
         $results1=$conn->query($sql1); 
            require_once("dbconfig.php");
?>
```

I have a table `book` there is lot of values there. If I choose the date it must be display all of the same values where dates are the same.

`$cid=1;`

[book table[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VrDP.jpg)

[doctor_availability](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnItF.jpg)

[it wont display the expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL87q.jpg)

Comment: If the other query worked then why are you not using it?

Comment: tbh I am new in php, I want the value of cic in manager_clinic table. it just displays 1 from ```$cid=1;```

Comment: There is nothing displaying here. What is `cic`? What exactly do you want to do here?

Comment: @MjM Why should they try it? You barely changed anything.

Comment: @user3783243 The second `require_once` is useless here, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Dharman Check her query there you can see php varibles which are not binding properly.

Comment: do I need to make this same? ``` $did=$_POST['doctor'];```
        $cid=1;```

Comment: @MjM That is true. There is no binding here, but you didn't add any binding either...

Comment: @MjM Your query isn't binding either. The variables are in double quotes so they will be expanded fine.

Comment: omg. haha I am a newbie here.. >.< that code wasn't mine, Im just manipulating it. and I want to do with is. not just get the value 1 of cid. I initialize it as 1 ``` $cid=1;```

Comment: You likely need to join the `manager_clinic` table. It is unclear to me where your issue is though. You should create your query first, then bring it to PHP. In PHP you should use parameterized queries.

Comment: @SherwinEstrera You need to rewrite your quesiton to make it more clear. What are your DB tables and columns. What is your expected output? What is the current output? Be more descriptive in your question, but keep it to the point.

Comment: @SherwinEstrera Please try this code  `var_dump($results1);`  below  `$results1=$conn->query($sql1);`

Comment: @SherwinEstrera Debug using `var_dump()` which will help you to debug line by line. Put this code `var_dump($results1);` at last and tell me what's the output

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure, but I think you need JOINs and definitely you need prepared statements. See my code below. I used JOINs to connect the 3 tables together and then I used your session value to match the `mid`.

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'dbconfig.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM book 
        JOIN doctor_availability USING(did)
        JOIN manager_clinic USING(cid)
        WHERE dov=? AND did=? AND mid=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('sii', $_POST['dateselected'], $_POST['doctor'], $_SESSION['mgrid']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results1 = $stmt->get_result();
}
```

Comment: This is the second part of your code from question. After `<?php`. Don't just blindly paste it into your code. Try to understand what is happening first. Read about MySQL joins and prepared statements.

Comment: can I send you my code? and the expected output graphically? I am having a trouble to understand it.

Comment: You can edit your question and paste your updated code there and also upload image here.

Comment: check it sir. please

Comment: Could you also show the contents of `doctor_availability` and `manager_clinic`?

Comment: check it sir. I think the problem is in ```$cid=1;``` that's why it shows the contents with the CID value of 1

Comment: Im sorry. I mean in my code. if i change it to $cid=2; it just display the contents with the CID value of 2 in my book table. did you check my doctor_availability and manager_clinic tables?

Comment: The problem is with your data. You lack referential integrity. The other 2 tables do not have entries with `CID=2`, so the query will not work properly. My query should work fine if you add the right data into your tables

Comment: sorry. I upload the wrong one, psls check it again sir

Comment: What is the ID of DR KWAK KWAK

Comment: the ID of DR KWAK KWAK is 13 sir

Comment: my code sir. I dont know how to use your code, Im new in PHP

Comment: I replaced `$conn->query($sql1);` with `prepare`, `bind_param` & `execute` The output remains the same `$results1 = $stmt->get_result()` should have your data. I used session values so make sure to add `session_start()`.

Comment: I want to stick it with my code. ```$cid=1;``` if I change it to ```$cid=55;``` it display the book with cid values of 55. but the content with the cid value of 1. wont display. the two has the same dov, wherein my case, if I choose the date. it must be display all the contents where the values of dov are the same.

Comment: Then remove `AND CID= $cid` from your query. If you do not compare then you will see all records.

Comment: @SherwinEstrera If this solves it see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work